# Can I deploy CakePHP web application and BottlePy base WebServices API on same server?

Tags: web-services, apache, cakephp, web-applications, bottle

I have a CakePHP based web application deployed on Apache (LAMP stack). Now I am doing a Web Services API using bottlePy that will expose services to be consumed by an Android application. The thing is both the applications will be working of the same MySql DB tables and reading/writing to the same. The reason its been done this way is because the CakaPHP based application is already available and was done a while back. Now we have a need to do an Android app and hence need to expose a Web Services API and since I am more comfortable with Python I would rather use. But before I dive deep in this direction I wanted to get answer to the following:

1. Can I have both the CakePHP web app and BottlePy based Web Services API served from the same Apache server? If not what will be an alternate?
2. Will two different apps accessing the same MySQL DB cause any issues in terms of locks, data integrity etc?
3. Anything else I need to be careful about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have implemented it anyways and it has been working great. I guess that answers the question, that yes it can be done.

1. I have both cakephp and bottlepy app served from same apache server.
2. I havent seen any issues and data gets written from both cakephp web app and bottlepy web api connected to android app.
3. Getting cakephp and bottlepy served from same apache server was a bit tricky but I got it working. I am not a webserver expert so dont know if the problems I faced were trivial or I solved something difficult. In either case it is working. If you face similar issues, let me know and I will post a detailed reply on how I did the setup.